# Using Urllib2 with 511 api that requires token

Tags: python, api

So, all I want to do is send a request to the 511 api and return the train times from the train station. I can do that using the full url request, but I would like to be able to set values without paste-ing together a string and then sending that string. I want to have the api return the train times for different stations.  I see other requests that use headers, but I don't know how to use headers with a request and am confused by the documentation.

This works...

```
urllib2.Request("http://services.my511.org/Transit2.0/GetNextDeparturesByStopCode.aspx?token=xxxx-xxx&stopcode=70142")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
the_page = response.read()
```

I want to be able to set values like this...

```
token = xxx-xxxx
stopcode = 70142
url = "http://services.my511.org/Transit2.0/GetNextDeparturesByStopCode.aspx?"
```

... and then put them together like this...

```
urllib2.Request(url,token, stopcode)
```

and get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing piece is "urllib" needs to be used along with "urllib2". Specifically, the function urllib.urlencode() returns the encoded versions of the values.

From the urllib documentation [here](https://pymotw.com/2/urllib/)

```
import urllib

query_args = { 'q':'query string', 'foo':'bar' }
encoded_args = urllib.urlencode(query_args)
print 'Encoded:', encoded_args

url = 'http://localhost:8080/?' + encoded_args
print urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

So the corrected code is as follows:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
token = xxx-xxxx
stopcode = 70142
query_args = {"token":token, "stopcode":stopcode}
encoded_args = urllib.urlencode(query_args)


request = urllib2.Request(url+encoded_args)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

print(response.read())
```

Actually, it is a million times easier to use requests package and not urllib, urllib2.   All that code above can be replaced with this:

```
import requests
token = xxx-xxxx
stopcode = 70142
query_args = {"token":token, "stopcode":stopcode}
r = request.get(url, params = query_args)
r.text
```

Answer (score 0):

The [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) documentation would be a good place to start to learn more about different ways to plug in values.

```
val1 = 'test'
val2 = 'test2'
url  = "https://www.example.com/{0}/blah/{1}".format(val1, val2)

urllib2.Request(url)
```